# How to interact with external command line program using Python (on windows)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, parallel-processing, subprocess

I have a program (let's say program.exe) that can be executed on a command line. After being executed, it asks for some inputs, runs for a while, and gives some outputs. I need to write a python script that interacts with this program so that it can continuously send/receive inputs/outputs.

I have tried the libraries [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), but so far I have not managed to implement this functionality. If anyone knows how to do this I would appreciate a working example so I can adapt it.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It seems pexpect is what you are looking for. Since your question is not specific. That is all I can comment on.

Answer (score 0):

Receive inputs:
to grab some returned values from shell scripts you can use the argument standard input like `argv` and `argc`

to invoke cmd command:
Use the `system.os` and usit as `os("<your shell command>")`